# Laravel - Show Validation Errors in Form by getting values from the response received

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.8 and i am submitting my form using ajax, and form getting validated using the laravel controller. And if validation fails, in response i get the validation error messages, now i want to show those error messages in the form.

I looked for various solutions and ways to get access to the json response received however i failed to do so.

My Validation Code in User Controller

```php
$this->validate($request,[
            'name'  =>  'required|string',
            'email' =>  'required|email|unique:users',
            'password'  =>  'required|string|min:6'
        ]);
```

and i sent request to store my data using ajax.

So if any validation fails i get response as mentioned below in my network developer tab of chrome :-

```
{"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"email":["The email has already been taken."],"password":["The password field is required."]}}
```

So What i want to do is access those error messages and display them below my form. To notify users regarding the errors. However i failed to do so.

I tried this in my ajax error :-

```
error: function(data){
   var errors = JSON.parse(data);
   $('.errors').append("<p>"+ data.errors[error] +"</p> ");
}
```

Please help me in figuring it out.
Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ajax example can help you figure out how to get error data. for the data display format, i think you can do it.

```
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
    }
  }).fail(function(xhr) {
       let data = xhr.responseJSON;
       if (data.errors) {
          // error happen
          $("#target-div").text(data.message);
          let errorInfo = "";
          for(let inputName in data.errors) {
            errorInfo += inputName +":"+ data.errors[inputName].message.join(", ") + "<br>";
          }
          $("#target-error-info").text(errorInfo);
       }
   });
```

If responseJSON is not set or null you can try to use **let data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)**

Comment: Isn't it possible that i access the data.errors in error: function (err) instead of accessing it in success: function (data) . As i think when the form is unprocessed , it goes to error instead of success.

Comment: I just tested and i can access the data.message in success: however i can't access the same in error: , isn't there a way around for that?

Comment: try updated code. may be it can handle data from fail section

Comment: Thanks William got hints from your answer and made it working. I am using this method to achieve it.


error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    var err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                            
   $.each(err.errors, function(name, val) {
   $('#'+name+'_error').text(val);
});

Comment: Nice @VivekBora, if my answer help you please accept the solution so this question will mark as solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel validation error returns a 422 Status code, you can check with that:

```
 $.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(data, statusCode) {
       // its validation error code
       if (statusCode == 422 && 'errors' in data) { 
          var errorMessage = '<ul>';
          $.each(data.errors, function(k, msg){
              errorMessage += '<li>' + msg.join('</li><li>') + '</li>';

          });
          errorMessage += '</ul>';

          $('#errorDiv').html(errorMessage);
       }
    },
    ...
  });
```